# Page number while printing using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

Hi I'm creating a report system on angularjs that can print reports out.

I can break the pages uses pagebreak in css. However I cannot figure out how to put page numbers on.

Comment: are you using ng repeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing printing page number can be achieved by using CSS counter and pseudo class. I've implemented a simple example for this issue, you could refer to it:

**HTML**

```
<!--page1-->
<div class="pager">
    <h1>Page 1 title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laborum necessitatibus maiores nesciunt, blanditiis nihil error ratione quasi optio, quam, tempore. Dolore, quae nostrum labore aliquid accusantium modi beatae. Magni.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat fuga inventore magnam non, omnis temporibus excepturi, veniam hic voluptas minus autem laudantium, quis quos, ratione optio! Rerum quod, alias ipsa.</p>
</div>
<p class="page-breaker"></p>    

<!--page2-->
<div class="pager">
    <h1>Page 2 title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla laborum necessitatibus maiores nesciunt, blanditiis nihil error ratione quasi optio, quam, tempore. Dolore, quae nostrum labore aliquid accusantium modi beatae. Magni.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat fuga inventore magnam non, omnis temporibus excepturi, veniam hic voluptas minus autem laudantium, quis quos, ratione optio! Rerum quod, alias ipsa.</p>
</div>
<p class="page-breaker"></p>
```

**CSS**

```
@media print{
    body{
        counter-reset: pageNumber;
    }
    .pager{
        min-height: 800px;
    }
    .page-breaker{
        page-break-after: always;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .page-breaker:before{
        counter-increment: pageNumber;
        content: "Page:" counter(pageNumber);
    }
}
```

"counter-reset" will initialize the value of variable 'pageNumber' which is maintained by CSS. This variable will be increased by CSS rules (in this case, .page-breaker:before). It means that increase the page number per page-breaker.

**Screenshot:**

[image]